# pdf full screen with Navigation bar on top

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, xcode, pdfview

Hello together I found on this side a very good tutorial to add a Pdf view to my xcode project.

[Tutorial](http://www.n00bdev.com/archives/5)

But my problem at the end in ViewController .m the size for the pdf is set with

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 768, 800);
```

But this is for Ipad, how can I set it for iPhone, so that the pdf is showen fullscreen with navigationBar on top?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can use the frame of your parent controller that will be always true(if it displays correctly in iPhone and iPad).

Just like

```
//Gives the frame of parent controller.
CGRect frame=self.view.frame;
```

Now you can adjust Y offset as you needed. 
Ex.

```
frame.origin.y=100;
```